# How to detect user is mid-way inputting with an Input Method?

Tags: ios, uitextview, uikeyboard

If user is inputting in a UITextView using an Input Method such as Chinese Pinyin, there is a state where the Pinyin is already displayed in tne text view but user is still yet to choose the final Chinese characters. A screenshot will be much more clear:

[image]

I want to do some text completion for user, but should only do it for the real input(the Chinese characters user chooses) but not for the intermediate Pinyin input. So I need to detect this pending state.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Finally got it. Input methods like Pinyin are called `Multistage Text Input`. The first stage is called `Marked`, the second stage is called `Committed`. To determine whether it is in `Marked` stage, one should query `UITextInput` Protocol's `markedTextRange` property:

```
if (textView.markedTextRange != nil) {
    // Marked.
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you know where to detect when there is even a character inputted? I've tried `UITextViewDelegate`'s `textViewDidChange`, `NSNotificationCenter`'s `UIControlEventEditingChanged` and various other stuffs all to no avail..