# UITextView attributedText with Japanese keyboard repeats input

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextview

I need to use two different fonts in text view, so I set attributed Text in textViewDidChange. But for Japanese keyboard the input character is entered repeatedly.

It works for English keyboard. 
It also works for Japanese keyboard when you use normal text instead of attributedText.

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    textView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"TOTAL: %@", textView.text);

    textView.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: textView.text];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSLog(@"ADDED: %@", text);

    return YES;
}
```

Output:

```
2015-07-15 13:51:10.156 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] ADDED: a
2015-07-15 13:51:10.167 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] TOTAL: あ
2015-07-15 13:51:11.376 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] ADDED: a
2015-07-15 13:51:11.378 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] TOTAL: あああ
2015-07-15 13:51:12.054 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] ADDED: a
2015-07-15 13:51:12.055 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] TOTAL: ああああああ
```

Expected:

```
2015-07-15 13:51:10.156 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] ADDED: a
2015-07-15 13:51:10.167 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] TOTAL: あ
2015-07-15 13:51:11.376 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] ADDED: a
2015-07-15 13:51:11.378 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] TOTAL: ああ
2015-07-15 13:51:12.054 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] ADDED: a
2015-07-15 13:51:12.055 japKeyTest[32163:5765000] TOTAL: あああ
```

Any idea how to enter attributed text with Japanese keyboard and get normal result? (without extra characters)

Comment: It's amazing the coincidence: I just started a new job and this is one of the first bugs I am trying to fix. I can't believe this isn't affecting thousands of apps that support japanese!

Comment: Also: try to type "mika" using romaji and see if you get a "k" in the middle of extra characters! I'm sure it's the same bug.

Comment: This happens for me with a normal english keyboard as well.

Answer (score 8):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13457241/2535345) helped me figure it out:
Check if markedTextRange on the UITextView is not nil. This means that the user is in the middle of inputting a multistage character. Hold off on editing the attributedText until they are done.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this has shown me that the bug (and I believe it's a `UIKit` bug) manifests any time the `-attributedText` property of a `UITextField` or `UITextView` is modified during -`textView(Field)DidChange time` (just like in your example).

In my case I was able to change the code so that the updating didn't occur during that time (the updating in my case was not required at all, so this was easy).

If you need to update the attributed text at that time, all I can recommend is file a bug with Apple and wait (forever or longer).

Note that you may also see this bug even if you are only updating the -text property of these objects--because `UIKit` will sometimes (always?) go ahead and update the `-attributedText` property for you when you update `-text`. (you can see this by subclassing these objects and overriding `-setAttributedText:` and setting a breakpoint.

Good luck to you

Edit: I only have seen this bug with the Japanese keyboards so far, but as I gain more experience with my app's use of other languages, I wouldn't be surprised to see more problems.